# Article before the word “additional”

Tags: indefinite-articles

It is known that an indefinite article may be used before the word “additional” followed by a plural noun.

*Example:* An additional 5 sheets were used.

But phrases like “additional resources” (without an article) are also possible. Does it mean that an indefinite article should be used only when the word “additional” is followed by a determiner and a plural noun?

Comment: Consider "an additional application".  Or "an additional panelist was added to the program."  So, no.

Comment: Hi Xanne, but we are talking about plural nouns, aren't we?

Comment: But we have "an additional" that is not followed by a determiner and a plural noun. "application" and "panelist" are singular without a determiner.  That seems to prove your rule wrong.

Comment: Numerals are usually considered as being in a separate class from the determiner class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, yes. You are correct. You would always say things like:

An additional 10 units....

An added 50 barrels....

or

Additional units were needed.

Added barrels increased the total volume.

It's not necessarily the case for every single word or condition. But in general, and definitely for the word in question (additional), that is the rule.